# Angular range slider's attach-handle-values does not show the values

Tags: angularjs, slider

When I set `attach-handle-values='true'` to my `range-slider` from the [Angular Range Slider](https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider) plugin, the values do not show up as they do in the very last example from the [demo](http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/demo/). What am I missing?

Live: http://codepen.io/ianhd/pen/VvxPre

I should be seeing these:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They show up if you add:

```
show-values="true"
```

Not intuitive from docs but is opposite of the demo that removes them

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the `show-values` attribute.

Here ya go:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOYrBN

Answer (score 0):

This has drive me crazy to debug, thought it was adblocker, HTTPS restrictions, plugin version. But *finally*, the reason of this is the AngularJS version, you are using 1.3.14 whilst the demo page is using 1.2.15.

As the docs says, `showValues` attr's default value is true, so you shall not need it, but if you use a newer version than what this plugin actually use, for some reason that I've not digged on yet, you will need to explicitly set it to true as *charlietfl* mentioned.

Comment: Adding show-values='true' in my live demo actually fixed it.

Comment: That's what I and all of the answers here mention. My answer gives the *reason* behind it. Btw, that worked for you and you still didn't upvote any answer, sad.